# Navigate to the detail page of selected item in CollectionView

Tags: maui, collectionview

I am using .net MAUI . I want to navigate to a detail page of selected item in CollectionView. I have tried using selectionchanged but it opens blank page .My goal is to open a detail page of particular product that is selected. It was working in ListView but when I change it to collectionView it opens blank page. I'm attaching the relevant code , Please let me know If more information is required.

**Xaml code(page 1)**

```xml
<CollectionView SelectionMode="Single" 
                x:Name="listview" 
                IsVisible="true" 
                RemainingItemsThreshold="12" 
                SelectionChanged= "listview_SelectionChanged" 
                ItemsLayout="VerticalGrid, 2">
    
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Padding="18">
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="100" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="100" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="120" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="120" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Image Source="splash_logo.png"  Grid.RowSpan="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"/>
                <Label Text="{Binding prod_name}" TextColor="Black" FontSize="Medium" FontAttributes="Bold" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"/>
                <HorizontalStackLayout Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" >
                    <Label Text="Rs." TextColor="Black"/>
                    <Label Text="{Binding prod_price}" TextColor="Black"  LineBreakMode="TailTruncation"/>
                </HorizontalStackLayout>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

**xaml.cs code**

```cs
 private async void listview_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e) {

  if (e.CurrentSelection != null) {

    await Navigation.PushAsync(new cataloguepage {

      BindingContext = e.CurrentSelection as csv
    });
    
  } else {
    await DisplayAlert("Alert", "No Item Selected", "ok");
  }
}
```

**xaml code(Second page)**

```xml
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout Padding="15">
        <Label Text="{Binding prod_name}" TextColor="Black" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="Large" Padding="10" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
        <Label Text="{Binding prod_img}" TextColor="#289" Padding="10"  HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"  FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="Medium" HeightRequest="200" WidthRequest="100" VerticalTextAlignment="Center"/>
        <Label Text="{Binding prod_price}"  TextColor="Black" FontSize="Medium" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>
        <Label Text="{Binding prod_desc}" TextColor="Black"/>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Comment: change code to following and debug from here
 if (e.CurrentSelection is csv item)
    {
     await Navigation.PushAsync(new cataloguepage
     {

      BindingContext = item
     });
    }
    else
    {
     await DisplayAlert("Alert", "CurrentSelection is not valid", "ok");
    }

Comment: Thanks ....I tried this but it always shows if condition false

Comment: Debug from here, i ment investigate what type e.CurrentSelection actually is.. not obviously csv

Comment: i update the answer , I don't see a ItemSource for the CollectionView . Is it showing items ?

Comment: the problem in that answer is that you have defined parameter in second page and there is no parameter at time of navigation to second page... correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: e.currentselection is showing system.collections.generic.list 1 system.object ,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try the following code:

```cs
private async void listview_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e) {

  if (e.CurrentSelection != null) {

    await Navigation.PushAsync(new cataloguepage {
      // modify code as follows
      BindingContext = e.CurrentSelection.FirstOrDefault() as csv
    });
    
  } else {
    await DisplayAlert("Alert", "No Item Selected", "ok");
  }
  
}
```

Note:

The  `e.CurrentSelection` is a `IEmunerable<object>` list,so we can not cast it to an object.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this, but I don't see a Binding to the `CollectionView`?

`ItemsSource="{Binding csv}"`?

```cs
private async void listview_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CurrentSelection != null)
    {
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new cataloguepage
        {
            BindingContext = e.CurrentSelection as csv
        });
    }
    else
    {
        await DisplayAlert("Alert", "No Item Selected", "ok");
    }
}
```

in **secondpage** , then use selectedItem

```cs
public secondpage(csv selectedItem)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    BindingContext = selectedItem;
}
```

Comment: No this is not working